# Mandrill Email with Variable from extra javascript

Tags: javascript, email, fullcalendar, mandrill

We're trying to include the modal-body in the email sent below with MANDRILL.  How could we add the modal-body variable to the email, similar to the name, email, & message.  (We're using FullCalendar) Thanks so much!

```
],
     eventClick: function(event) {
  console.log(event)
    // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
  var start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
  html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
  var modal = $("#modal");
  modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
  modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
  modal.modal();
    }
});
});
});//]]> 
jQuery(function($)  
{
$("#contact_form").submit(function()
{
var content = $("modal").text();
    var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
    var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
    var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data: {
            'key': 'API',
            'message': {
                'from_email': "email@email.com",
                'from_name': "name",
                'headers': {
                    'Reply-To': "email@emailcom"
                },
                'subject': 'Confirmation -  Sign Up',
                'text':   modal, 
                'to': [
                {
                    'email': email,
                    'name': name,
                    'type': 'to'
                }]

            }
        }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
        $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
       var content = $("modal").text();
            document.writeln(content);
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        alert('Error sending message.');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send api request directly from javascript? if so you will expose Mandrill your API key to end user which is not good at all.

This is not the correct way IMO. Send a request to your back end with the user data and then from your back end you can send the mandrill API request.

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/sections/200775387-Templates-and-Dynamic-Content) it explains how you can send dynamic template using Mandrill.

Either you can use Handlebars to add your dynamic content. Another way is using `mc:edit` attribute in an HTML tag to replace tag content with you dynamic content.

First, you will need to upload your email template on the Mandrill account.
Add your tag with `mc:edit` attribute, something like this:

```
<span mc:edit="email">example@gmail.com</span>
```

and in your email call include this:

```
 "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "email", //attribute value that you pass in your email template.
            "content": "something@anything.com" //pass your dynamic email value here
        }
    ],
```

[Here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template) is the sample api call.

For your case:

```
 .....
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
                data: {
                    'key': 'API',
                     "template_content": [
                    {
                        "name": "email", //attribute value that you pass in your email template.
                        "content": "something@anything.com" //pass your dynamic email value here
                    },
                  ..... //You can pass multiple object similarly here 
                ],
                    'message': {
                        'from_email': "email@email.com",
                        'from_name': "name",
                        'headers': {
                            'Reply-To': "email@emailcom"
                        },
                        'subject': 'Confirmation -  Sign Up',
                        'text':   modal, 
                        'to': [
                        {
                            'email': email,
                            'name': name,
                            'type': 'to'
                        }]

                    }
                }
            })
    .....
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!  I've been reading up on handlebars.   Would handlebars allow for using variables, like I have above?  Would mc:edit?  Or should I try using merge tags?  We're having trouble setting it up with our existing variables.

Comment: You can use either.. Handlebars or Merge tags for dynamic content.. for Handlebars check this out..
https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content 
and for Merge tags.. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582487-How-to-Use-Merge-Tags-to-Add-Dynamic-Content
Both of provide same functionality.

Comment: But unlike `mc:edit` as attribute to tag you have to place your dynamically replaced variable between tags.. checkout the above links..